# ASP Gridview "Select All" issue with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I received an old ASP.NET code for review and fix the issues with minimum effort. While checking the code, I found, it is using simple ASP Gridview and then selecting all rows with a JavaScript. Also it is integrated with Jquery Datatable. Here is the code for Gridview -

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelgv" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" UseAccessibleHeader="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="ID,NAME,SALARY" Height="125px" Width="100%" OnPreRender="gv1_PreRender">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-Width="30px">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="allchk" runat="server" onclick="javascript:toggle(this);" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="selectchk" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" HeaderText="NAME" SortExpression="NAME" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SALARY" HeaderText="SALARY" SortExpression="SALARY" ControlStyle-Width="125" />
            </Columns>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <label style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center">
                        No Records Available
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:GridView>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is the Javascript to toggle the selection -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function toggle(source) {
            var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                if (checkboxes[i] != source)
                    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
            }
        }
</script>
```

And on page load here how they integrated Datatable -

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "", "<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function () { $('#gv1').dataTable({autowidth: false}).yadcf([{ column_number: 1 },{ column_number: 2 },{ column_number: 3 }]);});<" + "/script>", False)
```

Basic features including pagination, datatble, yadcf, search, sort functioning properly. If I stay on PAGE-1, click "Select All" checkbox, it is also working fine.

But problem arises when I go to any other page (say pagination 3), clicking "Select All" checkbox. It is reverting me to PAGE-1 keeping the selection intact on PAGE-3. If I again go back to PAGE-3, I can see all the rows selected.

I am not able to understand or fix why it is always toggling to PAGE-1 after  clicking "Select All" checkbox from other PAGE. How to fix this? Is this happening due to UpdatePanel? If Yes, how to fix this without removing that tag?

Note: This is happening ONLY when I am clicking on "Select All" checkbox not for individual row checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. This is happening due to default sort property of first column of jquery datatable. I have changed the datatable initialisation by modifying this -

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "", "<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function () { $('#gv1').dataTable({autowidth: false}).yadcf([{ column_number: 1 },{ column_number: 2 },{ column_number: 3 }]);});<" + "/script>", False)
```

to

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "", "<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function () { $('#gv1').dataTable({autowidth: false, order: [], aoColumnDefs: [{ 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0] }]}).yadcf([{ column_number: 1 },{ column_number: 2 },{ column_number: 3 }]);});<" + "/script>", False)
```